# Xenoforo create a new thread with curl

Tags: http, post, curl

I came to a stop to get curl to create a new thread in the Xenoforo forum software.

Httpfox gives me the following data to create a new thread:

Headers:

```
POST /forum/add-thread HTTP/1.1
Host    forum.tld
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Ajax-Referer  http://forum.tld/forum/create-thread
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://forum.tld/forum/create-thread
Content-Length  17871
Cookie  cookie stuff
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Raw post Data:

```
title=title+of+the+thread&message=urlencoded+thread+message&_xfRelativeResolver=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.tld%2Fforum%2Fcreate-thread&watch_thread_state=1&poll%5Bquestion%5D=&poll%5Bresponses%5D%5B%5D=&poll%5Bresponses%5D%5B%5D=&_xfToken=atoken&_xfRequestUri=%2Fforum%2Fcreate-thread&_xfNoRedirect=1&_xfToken=atoken+again&_xfResponseType=json
```

I extract the token from another page with curl by login in or using cookies.

When I use this curl:

```
curl -b cookie.txt -L -A "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" -e "http://forum.tld/forum/create-thread" --data-urlencode "title=$title" --data-urlencode "watch_thread_state=1" --data-urlencode "message=$message" --data-urlencode "_xfRelativeResolver=http://forum.tld/forum/create-thread" --data-urlencode "poll[question]=" --data-urlencode "poll[responses][]=" --data-urlencode "_xfToken=$token" --data-urlencode "_xfRequestUri=/forum/create-thread" --data-urlencode "_xfNoRedirect=1" --data-urlencode "_xfResponseType=json" "http://forum.tld/forum/add-thread"
```

It outputs:

```
{"error":{"message":"Please enter a valid message."}
```

The $message gets read from a text file encoded in iso-8859-1.

Any ideas? I'm kind of clueless right now.